# Clean code - best way to compact code in Java

Tags: java, code-cleanup

I have code that looks like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i < a; i++){
        List<Integer> list = elementA.get(i);
        SomeClass rg = new SomeClass(list, a, methodA(i));
        int result = rg.generate();
        var+=methodA2(i, result);
    }
    for(int i=0; i < b; i++){
        List<Integer> list = elementB.get(i);
        SomeClass rg = new SomeClass(list, b, methodB(i));
        int result = rg.generate();
        var+=methodB2(i, result);
    }
```

How can I avoid this code repetition? I can create function which does that, but what to do with this different methods?

Comment: It depends on the declarations of elementA and elementB, of methodA() and methodB(), and of methodA2() and methodB2().  If the get() methods of the classes are defined by a common interface or superclass, that helps.  As for the methods, we'd just have to know more about them -- do they correspond to the classes with get() in some fashion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Java < 8 you can create an interface (note that there already is an `IntFunction` interface in Java 8):

```
interface IntFunction<A> { A apply (int i); }

m(elementA, a, new IntFunction<A> () { public A apply(int i) { methodA(i); } });
```

And your method would look like:

```
private void m(Collection<List<Integer>> element, int a, IntFunction<A> f) {
    for(int i=0; i < a; i++){
        List<Integer> list = element.get(i);
        SomeClass rg = new SomeClass(list, a, f.apply(i));
        int result = rg.generate();
    }
}
```

(I have omitted the `methodA2` for conciseness: you would need a second interface that has an `apply(int, int)`)

That is quite verbose and the benefit is not obvious vs. repetition.

---

With Java 8 it becomes cleaner:

```
m(elementA, a, i -> methodA(i));
//or
m(elementA, a, this::methodA);
```

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ I have added a more detailed example.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the `IntFunction` interface [already exists in Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes I did pick the name on purpose!

Comment: I know, I assumed that you did - just might be worth stating it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

- Define a method that receives your `List<List<Integer>>` as argument that returns the desired data.
- Define an interface that will hold the *generic* methods like `method`, `method2` (based from your code).

For example:

```
public long yourFooMethod(List<List<Integer>> listOfData, int n, SomeInterface foo) {
    int i = 0;
    long var = 0;
    for(List<Integer> list : listOfData) {
        SomeClass rg = new SomeClass(list, n, foo.method(i));
        int result = rg.generate();
        var += foo.method2(i, result);
    }
    return var;
}
```